# ContentProviderClient release() deprecated

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contentproviderclient

I found some solution to delete database and recreate it using ContentProvider.

```
        ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
        ContentProviderClient client = resolver.acquireContentProviderClient(KOOPSContentProvider.AUTHORITY);

        assert client != null;
        KOOPSContentProvider provider = (KOOPSContentProvider) client.getLocalContentProvider();

        assert provider != null;
        provider.resetDatabase();

        client.release();
```

but in that **ContentProviderClient** class has `release()` which is **deprecated**, Is there any other way to free up resources.

Edited:
If I try to use **close()**, It is displaying as warning as follow.

> `This ContentProviderClient should be freed up after use with #release().`
>
> Many resources, such as TypedArrays, VelocityTrackers, etc., should be
>   recycled (with a recycle() call) after use. This lint check looks for
>   missing recycle() calls.

and **close()** displaying as disabled, why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in case anyone is wondering what the code should be:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
{
    client.close();            
}
else
{
    client.release();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is replaced by `close` but it is available only on API 24+

see more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderClient.html#close()

`close` on 24 is the same as `release` below 24
see source code of `ContentProviderClient`

```
  /**
 * Closes this client connection, indicating to the system that the
 * underlying {@link ContentProvider} is no longer needed.
 */
@Override
public void close() {
    closeInternal();
}

/**
 * @deprecated replaced by {@link #close()}.
 */
@Deprecated
public boolean release() {
    return closeInternal();
}
```

it is disable because you need to select correct `api level`
[image]

Comment: then What about older device?

Comment: `This ContentProviderClient should be freed up after use with #release().`

Many resources, such as TypedArrays, VelocityTrackers, etc., should be recycled (with a recycle() call) after use. This lint check looks for missing recycle() calls.

*Displaying as warning.*

Comment: I guess the `lint` warning is a bit misleading :)

Comment: use `release` on API 24 below, use a check using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` like mentioned here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes